# Use Google Apps and Mandrill/Sendgrid to send emails

Tags: email, dns, sendgrid, mandrill

Right now I have dilemma with email part of my projects. I'm using *Sendgrid*  to send and receive emails (via *webhook*). All email functionality is integrated in my web application and all the emails are stored in the database. I want to know is it possible to do next:

1. Use Google Apps to receive inbound emails for support@domain.com
2. Use Google Apps to send outbound emails from support@domain.com
3. Use SendGrid or Mandrill to send outbound transactional and news
   emails from noreply@domain.com and news@domain.com

Current problem is in MX records. Both Google and SendGrid MX records are required to be set in my DNS, but as far as I understand only one of them will actually work.

What is the best solution to make it possible? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution:

1. Point your MX records to google for your top level domain, domain.com.
2. Create support@domain.com email
3. Next, create a subdomain (i.e: sub.domain.com) and point the mx records to sendgrid.
4. Then, set up news@domain.com to forward to news@sub.domain.com. This way those emails get sent to your application.

*Nothing needs to changed for sending outgoing transactional emails with SendGrid. You can send emails from news@domain.com. I also recommend to NOT USE noreply@domain.com, this hurts your deliverability(https://sendgrid.com/blog/why-you-should-not-use-noreplydomain-com-in-your-emails/)*

Comment: I also have this case: So i want gmail to send the emails using the SendGrid SMPT, but i find no place to setup Sendgrid SMPT, how does that work? Right know im recieving emails with gmail google suite, but send is done by google servers...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to use a subdomain for either the inbound emails or the outbound emails, so that you can keep the MX records separate. Receive emails to `domain.com`, send from e.g. `mail.domain.com`